# Finding a keyword in a column and editing a new column in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to read Column C and find different keywords at the beginning of the text.
For simplicity let's call them KW1 and KW2. Based on the keyword found I have to edit Column D with a text.
If "KW1" in cell C2, add a column D and cell D2 will have the text "Keyword1".

I do not know how to deal with the ranges.
I am doing a "for each" loop on Column C but I do not know how to refer to this column nor how to edit a different column using a for each.

Dummy document
I would have to add a column between Column 3 and Column 4 to implement this concept.
[image: Here's a picture of a dummy document.]

The myRange variable doesn't make sense. I modified it  many times trying to make it work.

```vb
Sub Keyword()
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Column 3.5"
    Range("I3").Select
    
    myRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
    
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
    For Each cell In myRange
        If InStr(LCase(cell.Value), LCase("KW1:")) <> 0 Then
            cell.Value = "Keyword1"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Following methods should work (not tested)

Method 1: Loop rows

```vb
Sub Keyword()
    myRange =Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    For Each row In myRange.rows
            If InStr(LCase(cells(row,3).Value), LCase("KW1:")) <> 0 Then
                cells(row,4).Value = "Keyword1"
        end with
    Next
End Sub
```

Method 2: Loop cells in column C

```vb
Sub Keyword()
    myRange = Range("C2:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        
    For Each cell In myRange.cells
        If InStr(LCase(cell.Value), LCase("KW1:")) <> 0 Then
            cell.offset(0,1).Value = "Keyword1"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I can see how logically this can work but I haven't been able to test it as I am getting a run time error in the If Statement:

Run-time error '424': Object Required. 

Any idea of how can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: @VBANoob just edited my answer, i added .rows to first method and .cells to second one, ( not tested again, cause i'm on my phone sorry about that)